# Replicating the String.trim() function - Processing 3

Tags: java, string, processing, trim

I am trying to replicate the String.trim() function in processing. I know the the String.trim() functions removes tabs "\t" , newlines "\n" and spaces at the beginning and end of the string. Right now what I am doing removes all the spaces , tabs and newlines in string . How do I make it remove spaces , tabs and newlines just at the beginning and at the end of the string.

```
String myStringTrim(String str){
String returnString = "";
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
 if(str(str.charAt(i)).equals("\t") || str(str.charAt(i)).equals("\n")  || 
     str(str.charAt(i)).equals(" ")){
      continue;
 }
    returnString += str.charAt(i);
 }
   return returnString;
}// myStringTrim()
```

Comment: Why are you replicating the `trim()` function instead of just using the `trim()` function?

Comment: You'd need to add some logic to check whether you are at the beginning or end of the string.

Comment: @Kome I get that, but why is this your goal? Is this a homework assignment? Are you using the [tag:processing] language?

Comment: @KevinWorkman yes it's an assignment and i'm using the processing language

Comment: @Kome Please note that your teacher probably doesn't want you to simply copy-paste the answer from the internet. I recommend checking your school's academic honesty policy.

Answer (score 1):

A replicate is perfect when it matches the original one, so try to have a look at [Open JDK source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java) and go with this:

```
public String yourTrim() {

    int len = value.length;

    int st = 0;

    char[] val = value;

    while ((st < len) && (val[st] <= ' ')) {
        st++;
    }

    while ((st < len) && (val[len - 1] <= ' ')) {
        len--;
    }

    return ((st > 0) || (len < value.length)) ? substring(st, len) : this;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expression for that purpose then. It will make the same result by retrieving the match from the string provided. Considering that you would need only one word, you just have to serve yourself into the match group(0).

```
String mydata = " my test ";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(mydata);
if (m.find()){
  String result = m.group(0);
  System.out.format(result);
}
```

Output:

```
myTest
```

Edited:

As you would like to support regular expression such as "my test", I added this a different regular expression that you can use for that purpose.

```
String mydata = " my test \n";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w+[\\w\\s]*\\w+");
```

Output:

```
my test
```